# MSbuild 15.0 not building Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, xamarin.android

I'm trying to upgrade our build process to use `MSBuild 15.0` that comes with `VS2017`. Up to now we've been using `MSBuild 14.0`.

When I use `MSBuild 15`, I get this error.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Sdk.props(16,3): error MSB4184:
The expression "[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\devenv.isolation.ini)" cannot be evaluated. 
Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\devenv.isolation.ini'
```

It looks like `$(VsInstallRoot)` which is used by the props file is pointing to the wrong location.

Does anyone have any ideas about what might be going on or how to resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be loser error, for part of the problem anyway. I'd installed MSBuild standalone tools and was trying to use that hence the VsInstallRoot problem.

Comment: Can you please tell how did you resolve this? I am facing the same error.

Comment: Yes, we did the same as mcBIG stated above. Removed the separate MSBuild installation and used the MSBuild that comes with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

In my case helped to uninstall separate MSBuild installation. I use MSBuild only in Visual Studio and through gradle plugin.